# Probability returning to initial state

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, self-learning, markov-chains

[image]

Let $P=\begin{bmatrix}0&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\\frac{1}{2}&0&\frac{1}{2}\\\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $P^{(n+1)}=P^{(n)}P.$

I know that if you start in any vertex the probability of return after $n$ hops is the same $P_{11}^{(n+1)}=P_{22}^{(n+1)}=P_{33}^{(n+1)}$
then $$p_{11}^{(n+1)}=\frac{1}{2}p_{12}^{(n)}+\frac{1}{2}p_{13}^{(n)}$$
since $p_{12}^{(n)}+p_{13}^{(n)}=1$
$$p_{11}^{(n+1)}=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{2}p_{12}^{(n)}\right)$$
but I do not know how to solve this recurrence relation or if is right.

Comment: My interpretation is that the flea jumps to either of the other two vertices with probability $1/2$.

Comment: Being back at time $n+1$ means not being back at time $n$ and choosing the right vertex amongst two, hence $$p_{n+1}=\tfrac12(1-p_n)\qquad p_0=1$$ from which one gets readily $$p_n=\tfrac13+\left(-\tfrac12\right)^n\tfrac23.$$

Comment: Re your latest edit: first, the recurrence relation is right since it is in my previous comment (more seriously, that you do not even react to a comment except for questioning it in this devious way is something I find astonishing); second, to solve the recursion, look for a fixed point of the recursion, find that it is $\frac13$, and center the recursion around its fixed point, that is, consider $r_n=p_n-\frac13$. Then, *Miracolo!*, the recursion becomes $$r_0=\tfrac23\qquad r_{n+1}=-\tfrac12r_n,$$ and now you might be in position of solving this...

Comment: @Did Sorry, my English is bad so I often do not understand well what people are talking about. Going back to your comment, I'm failing to understand well what is this $p_n$ is any generalization you made?

Comment: "This" $p_n$ is your $p_{11}^{(n)}$.

Comment: @Did Ah think I understand, my recurrence relation has an error then.The right is $p_{11}^{(n+1)}=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-p_{11}^{(n)}\right)$, but I could not get the same thing you get.I have to assume something about $p_{12}^{(n)}$?

Comment: No, the explanation is in the first sentence of my first comment here.

Comment: Induction works:  (If I can squeeze it into a Comment.) Abbreviate $p_{11}^{(n)} = p_n.$ So $p_0 = 1, p_1 = 0 = \frac{1}{2}(1-p_0)  = 0 = \frac{1}{3}+(-\frac{1}{2})\frac{2}{3} = 0.$ Then $p_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}[1 - (\frac{1}{3} + (-\frac{1}{2})^n\frac{2}{3})] = \frac{1}{3} +(-\frac{1}{2})^{n+1}\frac{2}{3}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some related summary comments on ergodic Markov chains.

(There are several
fleas hopping around triangles elsewhere on this site, each according to the same transition matrix, but with
varying questions about the associated process; search 'Markov flea vertex'.)

With help from @Did, essentially by manipulating difference equations, I believe you have understood that 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} p_{11}^{(n)} = \lim_{n \to \infty} [1/3 + (-1/2)^n(2/3)] = 1/3.$$
The purpose of this comment is to put that accomplishment in context.

Indeed, $\lim_{n \to \infty} p_{ji}^{(n)} = 1/3,$ for all $i, j.\;$ Or, in matrix notation, $\text{P}^n$ converges to a $3 \times 3$
matrix in which all 9 entries are $1/3.$ Over the long run, the starting vertex is unimportant, and the chain spends 1/3 of
its 'time' at each vertex.

This is an 'ergodic' Markov chain. That is, there is a power $N$
such that $\text{P}^N$ has all positive entries. (In this case
$N = 2$.) Such an ergodic chain has a unique stationary distribution $\sigma$
(a 3-vector) such that $\sigma\text{P} = \sigma$ which is the same as the
limiting distribution (a 3-vector) with elements $\pi_i = \lim_n p_{ji}^{(n)}.$ That is, each of the three rows of the matrix $\lim_n \text{P}$ is the 3-vector $\sigma = \pi.$

The particular transition matrix $\text{P}$ of the Markov chain
of the current problem is 'doubly stochastic'; its columns (as well as its rows) sum to 1.
A Markov chain with such a $k \times k$ transition matrix has a stationary $k$-vector $\sigma$ with all elements equal. If such
a chain is ergodic then the limiting matrix $\lim_n \text{P}$
has all $k^2$ elements equal.

However, a chain with a doubly-stochastic matrix need not be
ergodic. For example, if the flea hops clockwise or counter-clockwise
(equal probability) to adjacent vertices of a SQUARE, then
the process is periodic with period 2. There is no power of the
transition matrix with all positive elements.

Some computations using R (other code or software may be more elegant):

```
 p = 1/2;  P = matrix(c(0,p,p,  p,0,p,  p,p,0), byrow=T, nrow=3);  P
 ##     [,1] [,2] [,3]
 ##[1,]  0.0  0.5  0.5
 ##[2,]  0.5  0.0  0.5
 ##[3,]  0.5  0.5  0.0

 P2 = P %*% P;  P2                    # 2nd power all positive elements
 ##     [,1] [,2] [,3]
 ##[1,] 0.50 0.25 0.25
 ##[2,] 0.25 0.50 0.25
 ##[3,] 0.25 0.25 0.50

 P4 = P2 %*% P2; P8 = P4 %*% P4;  P8  # 8th power already close to limit
 ##          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
 ##[1,] 0.3359375 0.3320313 0.3320313
 ##[2,] 0.3320313 0.3359375 0.3320313
 ##[3,] 0.3320313 0.3320313 0.3359375
 1/3 + (-1/2)^8 * 2/3                 # matches diagonal elements
 ## 0.3359375


 # Normed first eigen vector
 eig.vec = as.real(eigen(t(P))$vectors[,1]);  eig.vec/sum(eig.vec)
 ## 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333
```

Answer (score 0):

Transition probability matrix (P) in this case will be
$$
P=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0.5 & 0.5\\
0.5 & 0 & 0.5\\
0.5 & 0.5 & 0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Though $p_{ii}=0$ for $i=0,1,2$, it can be observed that $p_{ii}^n\ne0$ for $n\ge 2$ (also intuitive). Rest is a straight forward calculation depending on $n$.

Comment: You mean, computing the powers of P? Unless you explain why this can be done relatively easily... (Unrelated remark: this is not necessary.)

Comment: Exactly, by computing the powers of $P$ and choosing any of the initial distributions among $[1\,  0 \, 0 ]'$, $[0\, 1 \, 0 ]'$, $[0\, 0 \, 1 ]'$ .

Comment: Quote: "Unless you explain why this (computing the powers of P) can be done relatively easily..."