# Probability in a fixed die

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, self-learning, markov-chains

[image]

I have that transition matrix is $$\begin{bmatrix}0&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}\\\frac{1}{5}&0&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}\\\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&0&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}\\\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&0&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}\\\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&0&\frac{1}{5}\\\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&0\end{bmatrix}$$
If I did $P^{(n)}=P^{(n-1)}P$ I get that 
$$p_{66}^{(n)}=\frac{1}{5}(p_{61}^{(n-1)}+p_{62}^{(n-1)}+p_{63}^{(n-1)}+p_{64}^{(n-1)}+p_{65}^{(n-1)})$$

Comment: Hey, here is an idea! Why don't you apply the analysis of [this very recent question of yours](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1372056/) to this setting, since they are completely equivalent? Deal?

Comment: @Did I tried to approach this same way, the problem is that I am struggling to establish relations of recurrence in those exercises.That's why I was trying a different way.

Comment: What? Why not solve the first case instead of posting duplicates?

Comment: @Did  Why for me it was something different from the previous.

Comment: This is trictly equivalent except that the fly situation is a "die" with 3 results instead of 6. And the explanation in my *first* comment over there fully applies: which part of `Being back (on result 6) at time n+1 means not being back at time n and choosing the right result amongst (to be completed) possible ones` do you fail to get?

Comment: @Did Yes I failed, I can not understand how these recurrence relations work.

Comment: @Did Actually I'm not idly by, I'm looking for some references to specifically learn this part of recurrence. I'm learning alone, and I spend all day on the same question will not help at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is mistaken.  Let's look at the probability distribution of $X_2$ given $X_0=6$.

\begin{align}
& \Pr(X_2 = 6\mid X_0=6) \\[10pt] 
= {} & \Pr\Big( \underbrace{(X_1 = 1\ \&\ X_2 = 6)\text{ or }(X_1=2\ \&\ X_2=6)\text{ or }\cdots}_{\text{five disjuncts}}\mid X_0=6\Big) \\[10pt]
= {} & \underbrace{\Pr\Big(X_1 = 1\ \&\ X_2 = 6 \mid X_0=6\Big) + \Pr\Big(X_1 = 2\ \&\ X_2 = 6 \mid X_0=6\Big) + \cdots\quad{}}_{\text{five terms}} \\[10pt]
= {} & \underbrace{\left( \frac 1 5 \right)^2 + \left( \frac 1 5 \right)^2 + \cdots \quad {} }_{\text{five terms}} = \frac 1 5.
\end{align}

And then:
\begin{align}
& \Pr(X_2 = 1\mid X_0=6) \\[10pt] 
= {} & \Pr\Big( \underbrace{(X_1 = 2\ \&\ X_2 = 6)\text{ or }(X_1=3\ \&\ X_2=6)\text{ or }\cdots}_{\text{four disjuncts}}\mid X_0=6\Big) \\[10pt]
= {} & 4\left( \frac 1 5 \right)^2 = \frac 4 {25}.
\end{align}

So we get $4/25$ for each of five outcomes and $1/5 = 5/25$ for the other outcome.

However, if we have $n$ instead of $2$, I think I'd express it as an $(n-1)$th power of a Markov chain transition matrix.  And *maybe* it would admit a closed form by solving a recursion.  And I say $n-1$ rather than $n$ because the problem as phrased goes from $1$ to $n$ rather than from $0$ to $n$.

The above shows why your first guess was wrong; now let's try to get it right. We have the transition matrix:
$$
P = \begin{bmatrix}0&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}\\\frac{1}{5}&0&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}\\\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&0&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}\\\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&0&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}\\\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&0&\frac{1}{5}\\\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&0\end{bmatrix}
$$

When a matrix has a constant diagonal and a constant off-diagonal, then one can use the following trick.  Write it as a linear combination of the matrix that projects orthongonally onto the space spanned by $(1,1,1,\ldots,1)^T$ and the matrix of the complement of that projection.  The mapping $(a_1,\ldots,a_6) \mapsto (\bar a,\ldots, \bar a)$, where $\bar a = (a_1+\cdots+a_6)/6$, is the first orthongonal projection.  The complement is $(a_1,\ldots,a_6) \mapsto (\bar a_1-\bar a,\ldots, a_6 - \bar a)$. Those matrices are therefore
$$
A= \begin{bmatrix} \frac16 & \frac16 & \frac16 & \frac16 & \frac16 & \frac16 & \\
\frac16 & \frac16 & \frac16 & \frac16 & \frac16 & \frac16 \\
\frac16 & \frac16 & \frac16 & \frac16 & \frac16 & \frac16 \\
\frac16 & \frac16 & \frac16 & \frac16 & \frac16 & \frac16 \\
\frac16 & \frac16 & \frac16 & \frac16 & \frac16 & \frac16 \\
\frac16 & \frac16 & \frac16 & \frac16 & \frac16 & \frac16 \end{bmatrix}
\text{ and }B = \begin{bmatrix}\frac56&\frac{-1}{6}&\frac{-1}{6}&\frac{-1}{6}&\frac{-1}{6}&\frac{-1}{6}\\
\frac{-1}{6}&\frac56&\frac{-1}{6}&\frac{-1}{6}&\frac{-1}{6}&\frac{-1}{6}\\
\frac{-1}{6}&\frac{-1}{6}&\frac 5 6&\frac{-1}{6}&\frac{-1}{6}&\frac{-1}{6}\\
\frac{-1}{6}&\frac{-1}{6}&\frac{-1}{6}&\frac56&\frac{-1}{6}&\frac{-1}{6}\\
\frac{-1}{6}&\frac{-1}{6}&\frac{-1}{6}&\frac{-1}{6}&\frac56&\frac{-1}{6}\\
\frac{-1}{6}&\frac{-1}{6}&\frac{-1}{6}&\frac{-1}{6}&\frac{-1}{6}&\frac56\end{bmatrix}
$$
We will write $P=\alpha A + \beta B$.

The advantage of this is that we can then exploit the fact that
\begin{align}
A^2 & =A, \tag 1 \\
B^2 & =B, \tag 2 \\
AB =BA & =0. \tag 3
\end{align}

Solving the system, we get $\alpha= -1/5$ and $\beta=1$.  Then by $(1)$, $(2)$, and $(3)$ above, we have
$$
P^n= \alpha^n A + \beta^n B.
$$

BTW, this experiment *can* be done with an ordinary (un-"fixed") die: just discard each outcome that is the same as the previous one.

Comment: I did $P^{(n)}=P^{(n-1)}P$ and I get $$p_{66}^{(n)}=\frac{1}{5}(p_{61}^{(n-1)}+p_{62}^{(n-1)}+p_{63}^{(n-1)}+p_{64}^{(n-1)}+p_{65}^{(n-1)})$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $P$ is symmetric, we know from the spectral theorem that $P$ has real eigenvalues and is diagonalizable. Since $P$ is a doubly stochastic matrix, the stationary distribution is uniform, i.e. $$\pi=\left(\frac16,\frac16,\frac16,\frac16,\frac16,\frac16\right).$$
Since $P$ has a stationary distribution, we know that $1$ is an eigenvalue. In particular,
$$P\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$
Since $P$ is a stochastic matrix, we know that each eigenvalue $\lambda$ satisfies $|\lambda|\leqslant 1$. Further, if $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $P$, then
$$\sum_{i=1}^6\lambda_i = \operatorname{Tr} P = 0. $$
Observe that if $v = (1, 0,\ldots, -1,\ldots, 0)$, i.e. the first component of $v$ is $1$, exactly one other component is $-1$, and the other components are zero, then $Pv=-\frac15 v$. Therefore $P=ADA^{-1}$ where
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1&1&1 \\1&-1&0&0&0&0\\1&0&-1&0&0&0\\1&0&0&-1&0&0\\1&0&0&0&-1&0\\1&0&0&0&0&-1 \end{bmatrix}$$
and 
$$ D = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0&0&0\\ 0 & -\frac15 & 0 &0 &0 &0\\ 0& 0& -\frac15 &0 & 0 &0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac15 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac15 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac15\end{bmatrix}$$
Since $D$ is diagonal, $$(ADA^{-1})^n = AD^nA^{-1}. $$
Now, from [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse%20%7B%7B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C-1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C-1%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C0%2C-1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C-1%2C0%7D%2C%20%7B1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C-1%7D%7D) we have
$$ A^{-1} = \frac16\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1&1&1\\1&-5&1&1&1&1\\1&1&-5&1&1&1\\1&1&1&-5&1&1\\1&1&1&1&-5&1\\1&1&1&1&1&-5\end{bmatrix}. $$
I used Matlab to compute $AD^nA^{-1}$ as
$$\small\frac16\begin{bmatrix}1+\left(-\frac15\right)^{n-1} & 1 - \left(-\frac15\right)^n & 1 - \left(-\frac15\right)^n & 1 - \left(-\frac15\right)^n & 1 - \left(-\frac15\right)^n & 1 - \left(-\frac15\right)^n\\
1 - \left(-\frac15\right)^n & 1+\left(-\frac15\right)^{n-1} & 1 - \left(-\frac15\right)^n & 1-\left(-\frac15\right)^n & 1-\left(-\frac15\right)^n & 1-\left(-\frac15\right)^n\\ 1- \left(-\frac15\right)^n & 1-\left(-\frac15\right)^n & 1+\left(-\frac15\right)^{n-1} & 1-\left(-\frac15\right)^n & 1-\left(-\frac15\right)^n & 1-\left(-\frac15\right)^n\\1-\left(-\frac15\right)^n & 1-\left(-\frac15\right)^n & 1-\left(-\frac15\right)^n & 1+\left(-\frac15\right)^{n-1} & 1-\left(-\frac15\right)^n & 1-\left(-\frac15\right)^n\\ 1-\left(-\frac15\right)^n & 1-\left(-\frac15\right)^n & 1-\left(-\frac15\right)^n & 1-\left(-\frac15\right)^n & 1+\left(-\frac15\right)^{n-1} & 1-\left(-\frac15\right)^n \\ 1-\left(-\frac15\right)^n & 1-\left(-\frac15\right)^n & 1-\left(-\frac15\right)^n & 1-\left(-\frac15\right)^n & 1-\left(-\frac15\right)^n & 1+\left(-\frac15\right)^{n-1}\end{bmatrix} $$
Hence,
$$\mathbb P(X_n = 6 \mid X_0 = 6) = (P^n)_{66} = 1+\left(-\frac15\right)^{n-1}$$
and
$$\mathbb P(X_n = 1\mid X_0 = 6) = (P^n)_{61} = 1-\left(-\frac15\right)^n.$$

Note that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} (P^n)_{ij} = \frac16 $$ for all $i,j$, consistent with the Markov chain being irreducible and aperiodic.